# Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <NavLink> outside a <Router> using mbdreact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, mdbootstrap

I'm trying to implement a navbar using mbdreact, but I keep getting this error:

> Error: Invariant failed: You should not use `<NavLink>` outside a
>   `<Router>`

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    MDBNavbar, MDBNavbarBrand, MDBNavbarNav, MDBNavItem, MDBNavLink, MDBNavbarToggler, MDBCollapse, MDBDropdown,
    MDBDropdownToggle, MDBDropdownMenu, MDBDropdownItem, MDBIcon
} from "mdbreact";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

class NavMenu extends Component {
    state = {
        isOpen: false
    };

    toggleCollapse = () => {
        this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <Router>
                <MDBNavbar color="default-color" dark expand="md">
                    <MDBNavbarBrand>
                        <strong className="white-text">Navbar</strong>
                    </MDBNavbarBrand>
                    <MDBNavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleCollapse} />
                    <MDBCollapse id="navbarCollapse3" isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
                        <MDBNavbarNav left>
                            <MDBNavItem active>
                                <MDBNavLink to="#!">Home</MDBNavLink>
                            </MDBNavItem>
                            <MDBNavItem>
                                <MDBNavLink to="#!">Features</MDBNavLink>
                            </MDBNavItem>
                            <MDBNavItem>
                                <MDBNavLink to="#!">Pricing</MDBNavLink>
                            </MDBNavItem>
                            <MDBNavItem>
                                <MDBDropdown>
                                    <MDBDropdownToggle nav caret>
                                        <div className="d-none d-md-inline">Dropdown</div>
                                    </MDBDropdownToggle>
                                    <MDBDropdownMenu className="dropdown-default">
                                        <MDBDropdownItem href="#!">Action</MDBDropdownItem>
                                        <MDBDropdownItem href="#!">Another Action</MDBDropdownItem>
                                        <MDBDropdownItem href="#!">Something else here</MDBDropdownItem>
                                        <MDBDropdownItem href="#!">Something else here</MDBDropdownItem>
                                    </MDBDropdownMenu>
                                </MDBDropdown>
                            </MDBNavItem>
                        </MDBNavbarNav>
                        <MDBNavbarNav right>
                            <MDBNavItem>
                                <MDBNavLink className="waves-effect waves-light" to="#!">
                                    <MDBIcon fab icon="twitter" />
                                </MDBNavLink>
                            </MDBNavItem>
                            <MDBNavItem>
                                <MDBNavLink className="waves-effect waves-light" to="#!">
                                    <MDBIcon fab icon="google-plus-g" />
                                </MDBNavLink>
                            </MDBNavItem>
                            <MDBNavItem>
                                <MDBDropdown>
                                    <MDBDropdownToggle nav caret>
                                        <MDBIcon icon="user" />
                                    </MDBDropdownToggle>
                                    <MDBDropdownMenu className="dropdown-default">
                                        <MDBDropdownItem href="#!">Action</MDBDropdownItem>
                                        <MDBDropdownItem href="#!">Another Action</MDBDropdownItem>
                                        <MDBDropdownItem href="#!">Something else here</MDBDropdownItem>
                                        <MDBDropdownItem href="#!">Something else here</MDBDropdownItem>
                                    </MDBDropdownMenu>
                                </MDBDropdown>
                            </MDBNavItem>
                        </MDBNavbarNav>
                    </MDBCollapse>
                </MDBNavbar>
                </Router>
                </div>
        );
    }
}

export { NavMenu };
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ICOM.Cbs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "mdbreact": "^4.19.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-async": "^7.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "validate-js": "^2.0.1",
    "validate.js": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.50.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/"
  }
}
```

I don't know why I keep getting this problem. I have tried to down grade react-router dom to 4.3.1, but it does not solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: `<BrowserRouter>` should be at root level component which clearly isn't and you are trying to use `<NavLink/>` component outside of `<BrowserRouter>` context.

Comment: @tarzenchugh: I have copied this code from their website as it is. But now I have tried to put BrowserRouter in my index.js file, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem implementing mdb dashboard, and in my case, updating the "react-router-dom" version to "5.2.0", solved the problem.